# How to style mhchem: MathJax?

Tags: html, css, mathjax

I am trying to write a chemistry equation on a website, but the content overflows the container and effects the responsiveness. I have used display: inline property with .MathJax class, it works fine with math equations but doesn't work with **mhchem**.

```css
<style>
  .MathJax, .MathJax_Display {
    display: inline!important;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: just dropping by to give a quick tip : you can use code fences instead of snippets since the snippet feature here is not necessary

Comment: Please edit the question with [mcve] with html aswell as css. It's impossible to answer the question without all the information.